# Coend of $\mathscr{D}(F(\bullet), G(\bullet))$

Tags: category-theory

([Crosspost](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250651/coend-of-mathscrdf-bullet-g-bullet) from Overflow)

Given categories $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{D}$ and functors $F,G: \mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$, we can form a bifunctor 
$$\mathscr{D}(F(\bullet), G(\bullet)): \mathscr{C}^\text{op} \times \mathscr{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$$
and the end of this functor is the set of natural transformations from $F \Rightarrow G$. (I guess we need $\mathscr{C}$ to be small in order to guarantee there is a *set* of such natural transformations, in general.)

Can I say anything about the coend? Is it some familiar thing?

Comment: Just a comment: I have seen something looking a bit like this recently in a talk, in the context of derived functors/homology of functors, where the functors went to an abelian category and they considered the coend of the (Deligne) box tensor product of the two functors. I don't know much about the subject, though. You might try to crosspost to MO.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Thanks, I crossposted it

Comment: You're welcome :) Put a link in each question redirecting to the other one, please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted and answered at mathoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question on the proof of the existence of rank function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250651/question-on-the-proof-of-the-existence-of-rank-function)